# Pinescript tradingview indicator on previous candle value

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am writing a code that is triggered on the current candle value, but uses the previous candle's as well. I was successful however this code looks probably kind of funny :)

Is there an easier way of using the previous  candle value, i.o. repeating [..]?

Thanks a lot.

```
signal6a =( signal6[12] or signal6[11] or signal6[10] or signal6[9] or signal6[8] or signal6[7] or signal6[6] or signal6[5] or signal6[4] or signal6[3] or signal6[2] or signal6[1] or signal6 or signal6[13] or signal6[14] or signal6[15] or signal6[16] or signal6[17] or signal6[18] or signal6[19] or signal6[20] or signal6[21] or signal6[22] or signal6[23] or signal6[24] or signal6[25] or signal6[26] or signal6[27] or signal6[28] or signal6[29] or signal6[30] or signal6[31] or signal6[32] or signal6[33] or signal6[34] or signal6[35] or signal6[36] or signal6[37] or signal6[38] or signal6[39] or signal6[40]) and high >ta.ema(high, 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `math.sum()` function for this purpose.

If you want to check if `signal6` was `true` for 40 bars **consecutievly**, you would do it like below:

```
is_signal6a = math.sum(signal6 ? 1 : 0, 40) == 40
```

It will lookback the last 40 candles and return the number of times `signal6` is `true`. If that rolling sum is equal to 40, you know that `signal6` was `true` for the last 40 candles.

If you want to check if `signal6` was `true` for at least one bar (**this is your case**), you would do it like below:

```
is_signal6a = math.sum(signal6 ? 1 : 0, 40) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally would use a custom function to check if `signal6` is `true`:

```
checkForTrue(source, len) =>
    p = false
    for i=0 to len
        p := source[i]
        if p
            break
    p
```

Once you have this function, your code can be written as:

```
signal6a = checkForTrue(signal6, 40) and high > ta.ema(high, 8)
```